# 2D array isn't created as expected in C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

In a simple C# console application I have the following:

```
class Program

public static void Main()
{
    string s = Console.ReadLine(); //User enters the string: "integer, space, integer". Eg., "3 3"
    string[,] myArray = new string[s[0], s[0]];
.
.
.
}
```

Upon debugging, the value of myArray will show string[53, 53], but I'm expecting string[3, 3]. However, if I Console.WriteLine(s[0]), it prints "3".

I've tried

```
string[,] myArray = new string[(int)s[0], (int)s[0]];
```

with the same result.

Where are the 53's coming from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`s[0]` returns a `char` (the first char of the `string`), and if you cast a `char` to an `int`, then you get the char code of the char instead of the digit that you expect.
Try this:

```
string s = Console.ReadLine(); //User enters the string: "integer, space, integer". Eg., "3 3"
string[,] myArray = new string[int.Parse(s[0].ToString()), int.Parse(s[0].ToString())];
```

Note: it's better to use `int.TryParse` instead of `int.Parse`, because `int.Parse` throws an exception if the given string can't be converted to an `int`, but `int.TryParse` returns a `bool`:

```
string s = Console.ReadLine(); //User enters the string: "integer, space, integer". Eg., "3 3"
int i1;
int i2;
if (int.TryParse(s[0].ToString(), out i1) && int.TryParse(s[0].ToString(), out i2))
{
    string[,] myArray = new string[i1, i2];
    // your other code
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert the char to an int.");
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't explain how he got 53...  '3' should be 51, unless he tested with '5 5'.

Comment: @CharlesW My bad. I did test originally with "5 5". Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

You will fist have to split your string into the two number parts

```
string s = "12 34";
string parts[] = s.Split();
// Now parts[0] contains "12"
//     parts[1] contains "34"

int i1, i2;
if (parts.Length == 2 &&
    Int32.TryParse(parts[0], out i1) &&
    Int32.TryParse(parts[1], out i2) )
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you and good catch. Two digit integers wouldn't have worked in the previous case.